# конвертирование url --> pdf --> jpg(скриншот) python

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, web-scraping

вопрос заключается в получении скриншота по ссылке, но без открытия браузера. Раньше были рабочие методы на selenium, а теперь как я понимаю приходится скачивать pdf по ссылке и уже от туда изымать нужный скриншот конвертируя в jpg страницу. Кода с набросками у меня нету потому что все ответы на мой вопрос написаны на старых модулях, что теперь являются не рабочими. Прошу помочь с написанием алгоритма подобного действия(если есть вариант не конвертировать, а просто сделать скриншот по ссылке без запуска браузера, то подойдёт ещё намного лучше)

Comment: И какая часть алгоритма Вам не понятна? В чём вопрос?

Comment: selenium можно запускать в фоновом режиме (headless)
так же можно делать скриншот (from PIL import Image)

Comment: @nomnoms12 мне не понятна сама реализация. Какие модули использовать, да и каким образом

Comment: @АндрейКрузлик нужен универсальный метод, без использования браузера, но спасибо за совет

Comment: @Интик универсальный для браузеров, то есть чтобы не подбирать драйвера для каждого. И поэтому отсутствие принадлежности браузеров здесь как по мне является лучшим решением